# How do I establish trustlines for kelp on the real network?

Tags: kelp

I am trying to run Kelp on the live network, just noodling around with MOBI-XLM and amgetting this error:

> error: your trading account does not have the required trustlines: [MOBI:GA6HCMBLTZS5VYYBCATRBRZ3BZJMAFUDKYYF6AH6MVCMGWMRDNSWJPIH]

My trading account is my Lobstr XLM wallet.

How do I make a trustline with MOBI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not entirely sure how to do this through Kelp itself, you can easily do this through https://laboratory.stellar.org/#?network=public.

Simply build a transaction with a `Change Trust` operation, sign it with your Kelp account's secret key, and submit it to the network.

Comment: I wasn't able to get the laboratory to work, but after seeing what it did I was able to get it to work in stellar_dotnet_sdk.  Thanks for pointer!